Por onde andam os desenvolvedores lusófonos?
Achei o fato curioso e talvez a discussão seja interessante.

Estava lendo o resultado do Developer Survey 2024.
Não tenho números aqui, mas relativamente à população dos países lusófonos, imagino que há mais desenvolvedores nestes, se comparado com países como Holanda e Polônia, mas curiosamente estamos atrás desses países em participação no SO:

Estados Unidos não é surpresa, mas estamos, em números de profissionais de TI, à frente de outros país com mais respresentatividade na pesquisa, isso me faz tentar imaginar o que acontece.

Não respondemos a pesquisa?
Não participamos do SO (digo, não estamos escritos e apenas lemos)?
Se não estamos inscritos, onde vamos buscar informações ou onde participamos de forma mais ativa?

Apenas algumas perguntas me vem à cabeça.

Pode ser que a quantidade de usuários ativos tenha caído. Eu praticamente abandonei o SO, entro só uma vez lá que outra, nem lembrava que tinha esse survey e não o respondi porque não o vi, deve ter acontecido durante um período que não entrei

Os EUA possuem cerca de 4.4 milhões de desenvolvedores, enquanto o Brasil possui cerca de 500 mil, são nove vezes mais desenvolvedores, enquanto a pesquisa do Stackoverflow indica que houve aproximadamente nove vezes mais participantes respondendo essa pergunta nos EUA do que no Brasil, então os números absolutos não são tão diferentes nesse sentido.
Além disso, segundo dados da Distant Job, Países Baixos e Polônia possuem respectivamente 320 mil e 295 mil desenvolvedores vivendo em seu território.
Dou ênfase à parte do vivendo em seu território pois a pergunta que foi feita pelo Stackoverflow foi "onde você vive?" e não "qual sua nacionalidade?", o que também poderia ajudar a explicar a diferença de quantidade, visto que com certeza você encontrará mais brasileiros indo viver nesses dois países do que o contrário.

Então, sim, a porcentagem de pessoas respondendo ao Stackoverflow, ao menos nos Países Baixos e na Polônia é maior, mas não tanto, acredito que o fator que mais impressiona é na verdade a diferença na quantidade de desenvolvedores em relação à população total do país, já que esses dois citados possuem, somados, um quarto da população do Brasil. Mas se formos seguir por esse lado, China e India que possuem mais desenvolvedores que o próprio EUA (naturalmente, afinal são de longe os países mais populosos do mundo), não tiveram nem de longe tanta participação quanto os EUA.
